How can I disable the clipboard functionality when my EditText has focus

I want to disable this clipboard when my password edit text has focus. I'm having trouble with some text tha users can paste it.
This is my current code. The paste from the cursor is already disabled.
fun AppCompatEditText.disablePasteOption() {
    customInsertionActionModeCallback = ActionModeCallbackInterceptor()
    customSelectionActionModeCallback = ActionModeCallbackInterceptor()
    this.isLongClickable = false
    this.setTextIsSelectable(false)
}

With the code below, it worked but it's a workaround.
addTextChangedListener( object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        if (after - count > 1) {
            this@disablePasteOption.setText(s)
            this@disablePasteOption.setSelection(s.toString().length)
        }
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    }

})


Question isn't clear. What is "this clipboard"? What do you mean "trouble with some text tha users can paste it"? Are you talking about the Clipboard functionality of some keyboard that allows pasting through it?

@AhaanUgale Yes, it's exactly the functionality of some keyboard that allows pasting through it. I have a password field that its not allowed some characters but with the clipboard the users can cheat with this,
